# How to use style sheet within a controller

Tags: codeigniter, stylesheet

I am having an application, in which  I m showing some tabs through some xyz view.
if anyone click on any of the tab it will call one of the function within a controller.

This called controller function will then display some values based on the id passed through the tab.

So I want to display those values through controller as well as to apply some style to generated output using some style.css file.

Now my application is generating the output but I am unable to apply styles on it. Specially .hover style is not working.

Comment: post some code for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can include your style files into your application. For this, it is recommended to have an `header.php` file, and after including all needed style sheets into this file, you can load and use it.